# Member Mapping Error, MVC 2 and EF4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4

I created my own entity to go with the stored procedure I wrote. The mappings for said SP and Entity seemed to go fine, now I'm getting this error (out pf the blue too)

> Error 7   Error 2019: Member Mapping
>   specified is not valid. The type
>   'Edm.Decimal[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,Precision=19,Scale=4]'
>   of member 'ItemPrice' in type
>   'GodsCreationTaxidermyModel.StoreItem'
>   is not compatible with
>   'SqlServer.varchar[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,MaxLength=15,Unicode=False,FixedLength=False]'
>   of member 'ItemPrice' in type
>   'GodsCreationTaxidermyModel.Store.StoreItems'.    F:\Projects\GodsCreationTaxidermy\GodsCreationTaxidermy.Data\GCTModel.edmx  1071    17  GodsCreationTaxidermy.Data

Got any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception says that your conceptual model (entity) has `ItemPrice` defined as `decimal` but your storage model (database description or stored procedure) returns it as `VARCHAR(15)`. EDMX consists of several layers and these layers don't correspond in for `ItemPrice`. Something is wrong in your mapping.

Comment: Thanks that was almost the exact probem